# About some representations of binomial CDFs

Tags: probability, statistics

The CDF of a binomial distribution is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). 
  $$F(k;n,p) = Pr (X \le k)
  =  I_{1-p}(n-k, k+1),
$$
where
$$
I_{1-p}(n-k, k+1)= (n-k){n \choose k}\int_0^{1-p} t^{n-k-1} (1-t)^k dt $$

I try to express $I_p(k+1,n-k)$ as $$I_p(k+1,n-k) =(k+1){n \choose n-k-1}\int_0^p t^k(1-t)^{n-k-1}dt$$

First question: Is this formula true?

Second question: is it  true that $I_p ( k+1,n-k) = 1-I_{1-p}(n-k, k+1)$? If so, I need some hints to prove this identity.

Comment: Maybe try to type your question instead of using images!!!!!! (And maybe to slow down on the exclamation marks...)

Comment: sorry because this is first time i know this site. i try to type my formula but it's not successfully :(

Comment: How did you "try" and were "not succesful"? Please explain.

Comment: for example: i try to type integral symbol but i don't know how to do it? I don't know where i can find instruction to type math symbol in this site :(.Can you give me instruction? I will edit my question. I really need your help to solve my problem!

Comment: Looking at the source of a few questions should get you started. For a more systematic resource, see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: thanks, dear. i will edit my question a.s.a.p

Comment: I have modified my question.Plz help me!
Ps: Because this is first time I asked question in this site. Everything is so new to me. Sorry

Comment: Effort acknowledged. I further tidied up the text of your question, please study the result for your further questions on the site, if any. (Oh, and there is an answer too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That $I_{1-p}(n-k, k+1)=\displaystyle (n-k){n \choose k}\int_0^{1-p} t^{n-k-1} (1-t)^k dt $ for every suitable $p$, $n$ and $k$ means that, for every suitable $\color{green}{\mathbf x}$, $\color{red}{\mathbf i}$ and $\color{blue}{\mathbf j}$, $$
I_{\color{green}{\mathbf x}}(\color{red}{\mathbf i}, \color{blue}{\mathbf j}+1)=\displaystyle \color{red}{\mathbf i}{\color{red}{\mathbf i}+\color{blue}{\mathbf j} \choose \color{blue}{\mathbf j}}\int_0^{\color{green}{\mathbf x}} t^{\color{red}{\mathbf i}-1} (1-t)^\color{blue}{\mathbf j} dt.
$$
Apply this to $\color{green}{\mathbf x}=p$, $\color{red}{\mathbf i}=k+1$ and $\color{blue}{\mathbf j}=n-k$.

Re your second problem, recall that $F(k;n,p)=P[X\leqslant k]$ where the distribution of $X$ is binomial $(n,p)$. Since $X=n-Y$ where the distribution of $Y$ is binomial $(n,1-p)$, 
$$
F(k;n,p)=P[Y\geqslant n-k]=1-P[Y\leqslant n-k-1]=F(n-k-1;n,1-p).
$$
The identity you want to prove is equivalent to this one.

Comment: Thanks Did. I got it. Thank you so much again for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, do you know how to prove the (crucial) assertion that the distribution of Y is Bin(n,1-p)?

Comment: Your mean is: why distribution of Y is binomial (n,1-p)?
If possible, can you help me to prove? Didn't you prove based on probability mass function?

Comment: Hmmm... Accepting an answer usually means you are satisfied with it. How can you be satisfied if you do not understand it (I might be selling you crap...)? // What is the everyday-life interpretation of X?

Comment: I satisfy because my ideas about my question are same your hints. About your question: "why distribution of Y is binomial (n,1-p)?" I am trying to prove by used Probability mass function. I think your hints elicited for me to solve my next problems. I don't want to ask more question when i did not think about it. I hope you can understand my mind. Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: I do (understand your mind). But/And if the task of completing the proof should be more difficult than expected, do not hesitate to say so.

Comment: oh yep. I'm very much grateful for your enthusiasm. Thank you very much, Did :)